# Buildbot fails when running as a daemon on mac osx 10.8

Tags: macos, daemon, launchd, buildbot

I've set up a buildslave to manage mac osx builds on a small apple computer in my room. Everything installed smoothly and before I knew it my apple server began churning away at its first few builds with no problems at all.

Seeing as everything worked flawlessly, I added the buildslave as a daemon according to this guide:
http://trac.buildbot.net/wiki/UsingLaunchd

One reboot and `$ sudo launchctl start ch.pixelcloud.game.lightship` later and it stopped working. I noticed it also stops working when I start the buildslave via SSH and close my SSH connection.

After some googling I figured out that programs lose some common functionality (in this case, DNS lookups) when the user who started the process logs out. I seem to have fixed this by adding 8.8.8.8 to the list of DNS servers, but now I'm running into another issue and I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing it.

This is the error output in buildbot's web interface:

```
git --version
in dir /Users/thecomet/buildbot/slaves/lightship/basedir/test-macosx-i686-applebloom/build (timeout 1200 secs)
watching logfiles {}
argv: ['git', '--version']
environment:
  HOME=/Users/thecomet
  LOGNAME=thecomet
  PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
  PWD=/Users/thecomet/buildbot/slaves/lightship/basedir/test-macosx-i686-applebloom/build
  SHELL=/bin/zsh
  TMPDIR=/var/folders/zS/zSzxVZUsHyOdGytmqY0aUE+++TM/-Tmp-/
  USER=thecomet
  __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F6:0:0
using PTY: False
Upon execvpe git ['git', '--version'] in environment id 4320746024
:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thecomet/buildbot/slaves/lightship/lightship/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 424, in _fork
environment)
  File "/Users/thecomet/buildbot/slaves/lightship/lightship/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 502, in _execChild
os.execvpe(executable, args, environment)
  File "/Users/thecomet/buildbot/slaves/lightship/lightship/bin/../lib/python2.7/os.py", line 355, in execvpe
_execvpe(file, args, env)
  File "/Users/thecomet/buildbot/slaves/lightship/lightship/bin/../lib/python2.7/os.py", line 382, in _execvpe
func(fullname, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
program finished with exit code 1
elapsedTime=0.012076
```

Slave twistd.log:

```
2015-06-30 01:41:03+0200 [Broker,client]  startCommand:shell [id 761]
2015-06-30 01:41:03+0200 [Broker,client] RunProcess._startCommand
2015-06-30 01:41:03+0200 [Broker,client]  git --version
2015-06-30 01:41:03+0200 [Broker,client]   in dir /Users/thecomet/buildbot/slaves/lightship/basedir/test-macosx-i686-applebloom/build (timeout 1200 secs)
2015-06-30 01:41:03+0200 [Broker,client]   watching logfiles {}
2015-06-30 01:41:03+0200 [Broker,client]   argv: ['git', '--version']
2015-06-30 01:41:03+0200 [Broker,client]  environment: {'SHELL': '/bin/zsh', '__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING': '0x1F6:0:0', 'PWD': '/Users/thecomet/buildbot/slaves/lightship/basedir/test-macosx-i686-applebloom/build', 'LOGNAME': 'thecomet', 'USER': 'thecomet', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin', 'HOME': '/Users/thecomet', 'TMPDIR': '/var/folders/zS/zSzxVZUsHyOdGytmqY0aUE+++TM/-Tmp-/'}
2015-06-30 01:41:03+0200 [Broker,client]   using PTY: False
2015-06-30 01:41:03+0200 [-] command finished with signal None, exit code 1, elapsedTime: 0.012076
2015-06-30 01:41:03+0200 [-] SlaveBuilder.commandComplete <buildslave.commands.shell.SlaveShellCommand instance at 0x10186c1b8>
```

Master twistd.log:

```
2015-06-30 01:41:19+0200 [-] <Build test-macosx-i686-applebloom>.startBuild
2015-06-30 01:41:19+0200 [-] [Contact] Builder <buildbot.status.builder.BuilderStatus instance at 0x7fdc28bb3368> with tags None started
2015-06-30 01:41:19+0200 [-] <RemoteShellCommand '['git', '--version']'>: RemoteCommand.run [761]
2015-06-30 01:41:19+0200 [-] command '['git', '--version']' in dir 'build'
2015-06-30 01:41:19+0200 [Broker,42,(ip removed)] <RemoteShellCommand '['git', '--version']'> rc=1
2015-06-30 01:41:19+0200 [-] Source step failed while running command <RemoteShellCommand '['git', '--version']'>
2015-06-30 01:41:19+0200 [-] releaseLocks(<buildbot.steps.source.git.Git object at 0x7fdbf56f2810>): []
```

I can confirm the directory exists. Why am I getting this error?

Here is the `$ uname -a` of the buildslave in case it's relevant:

```
Darwin applebloom 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

I'm using Buildslave version 0.8.12 and Twisted version 15.2.1.